# Can't find python33 or run it in CentOS 7

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, centos

By default python 2.7 was installed on this OS, which can be accessed using the `python` command. I installed python33 on it, using this tutorial:

https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-python-3-in-centos-7/

Now, the python33 package is installed, but I cannot access it. I have tried the python33 command. I've also tried these:

```
find -name python33 
which python33
rpm -ql python33
```

But I get nothing. What should I do?

Comment: First of all as far as I know it's `python3` not `python33` but if you have tried that too, when you can not run it maybe you didn't installed it correctly, I think you should try with another ways.Also to be sure if python3 exists in your `/lib` directory maybe you need to create a `/bin` link for it to run in command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because python didn't installed in `/usr/bin/`.

it installed on `/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/`

Python 3.3 will become accessible by launching a new shell instance using the Software Collection scl command :

```
scl enable python33 bash
```

Answer (score 1):

The command itself is likely just **python3**

To check to see if it is installed do:
sudo yum info python3

if it isn't, use:
sudo yum install python3

I believe the only 3.x version available is 3.4, but I don't imagine you'll run into any version conflicts with what you are doing.

edit:
If it is installed, it might be python3.3, not python33

Comment: I did that, but it didn't help. I used scl enable python33 bash

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edit, but I missed something earlier: I believe the command is **python3.3** not **python33**